# Switch cursorline in vim on demand

Tags: vim

In vim editor, I want to switch cursorline on and off **on demand**.
I already have this in my .vimrc:

```
     set nocursorline
     noremap <F3> :set cursorline! <CR>
```

But this only works in normal mode. How to change, so the F3 key works in insert mode too?

I don't want to have cursorline at opening a new file directly, so "set nocursorline" is OK for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume by "edit mode" you mean "insert mode".  The trick for running normal mode commands from insert mode is to prefix them vith <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd>. Try this:

```
set nocursorline
nnoremap <F3> :set cursorline!<CR>
inoremap <F3> <C-o>:set cursorline!<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

map imap cmap noremap ... all do not solve my problem. Generally I want to use a key mapping definition which works in ex mode and edit mode at once.